# Division of double and float in c

Tags: c, double, division, digits

i believe that double have x2 precision of float .

in my calculator 10/3 is 3.3333333333333333333333333333333

when i do the following code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void main() {


    double var = (double )10 / (double )3;
    float var2 = (float )10 / (float )3;


    printf("%f %f \n" , var , var2 );

}
```

i get the same number of digits after 3, :

3.3333333333333335 3.3333332538604736

why do i get the same number of digits? and why the value is different ? and how to do a division for double and float and get all the numbers and digits in c (like in my calculator) ?

Comment: You do realize there's an infinite number of digits in 3.33333... If you want them "all" it's going to take a while.

Comment: Because `10/3` cannot be exactly represented by a floating point variable. The code is not printing `10/3` but the result of trying to store it in a variable with finite storage space. Your calculator is geared to the precision required by its display.

Comment: @WeatherVane and others, Curious, can you elaborate more on that? Windows calculator displays 31 "3" decimal places. Any idea if it's using some kind of larger/more precise internal data type than `double`? Maybe it has a lookup table of common fraction ==> decimal conversions? I've done zero research.

Comment: @yano is *must* be better than `double`, which is only useful for about 16 significant digits. If you would like to research, it is now [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator).

Comment: Per C 2018 7.21.6.1 7, a conversion with `%f` produces six digits after the decimal point. If you are getting “3.3333333333333335”, then either you did not use `%f` or your C implementation is defective.

Answer (score 2):

By default `printf` will only print a limited number of digits. On my system it's 6 digits. On your system it seems to be 16 digits.

To print more digits do:

```
    printf("%.60f \n%.60f \n" , var , var2 );
```

Output:

```
3.333333333333333481363069950020872056484222412109375000000000 
3.333333253860473632812500000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

As you can see neither `float` nor `double` can print

```
3.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

but - obviously - `double` is closer than `float`.

BTW: It's not `void main() {`. It shall be `int main(void) {`

Comment: _It shall be int main(void)_.  The latest specs have loosened up on this quite a bit.

Comment: AFAIK, when using `printf`, the float uses `%f`, but the double uses `%lf` (long float)...

Comment: @Myst Not when printing.

Comment: @Myst you are confusing with `scanf` which is different. A `float` passed to `printf` is promoted to `double`. In `printf` the format spec for `double` is `%f`.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane , you're totally right, I forget that one 

Comment: The C standard specifies that the precision of a floating point conversion in `printf` defaults to 6, not an implementation-defined value. To get 16 digits of precision, you'd need to specify an explicit precision.